# Compare if word in list and file are the same?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a list of 100 words. I want to see if those words show up in a file of ~100k words. If it does show up I want to print *word*:1 and if it shows again, print *word*:2

```
import io
from wordlistFile import *


words = ["APPLE", "ORANGE", "GRAPE"]





with io.open("Text.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8", errors='ignore') as file:
    file.readlines()
    print("5")
    
    
    wordlist = wordlistFile   #File imported         
    found_words = {}
    search_words = words
    
    print("6")
    for word in search_words:
        for item in wordlist:
            print("8")
            if word == item:
            #print("9")
                if word in found_words:
                    print("10")
                    found_words[word] += 1
                    print("11")
                else:
                    print("12")
                    found_words[word] = 1
                    print("13")
                    print(item + ':',found_words[word])
                    print("14")
```

The code only prints up until 7 and then spams 8

Comment: This smells like homework :D

Comment: You use `for item in wordlist:` but wordlist is empty. What do you expect should happen?